# Supermartingale-like property : does convergence still obtains?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

A super-martingale $\{X_n\}$ in discrete time is usually represented as having the defining property

$$X_n \geq E[X_{n+1} \mid \mathcal F_n] ,\;\; \forall \,n \tag{1}$$

where $\{\mathcal F_n\}$ forms an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields.

As pointed out in a comment to the original form of this question, this is equivalent to

$$X_n \geq E[X_{k} \mid \mathcal F_n] ,\;\; \forall \,n \leq k \tag{2}$$

which is the one providing the discrete analogue for the analogous condition for continuous time.

By the tower property of conditional expectation we have

$$E[X_{n+2} \mid \mathcal F_n] =E\Big( E[X_{n+2} \mid \mathcal F_{n+1}]\mid\mathcal F_n\Big) \leq E[ X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] \leq X_n \tag{3}$$

Verbally, standing at any period and looking two periods (or in fact any number of periods) ahead, we expect a lower value than the current one.

Consider now the following situation:

Let a (deterministic for simplicity) non-negative sequence $\{a_n\}$ for which we have that some individual elements of the sequence are smaller than unity, but also that

$$\forall n,\; \exists\; s(n) : \forall s \geq s(n),\; \prod_{j=1}^{s}a_{n+j} \geq 1 \tag{4}$$

Verbally, if you multiply enough of them, their product will eventually become equal or greater than unity.

Assume also that the following relation holds:

$$X_n = a_{n+1}E[X_{n+1} \mid \mathcal F_n],\;\; \forall\, n \tag{5}$$

Solving forward, this gives

$$X_n = \left(\prod_{j=1}^{s}a_{n+j}\right)E[X_{n+s} \mid \mathcal F_n]  \tag{6}$$

Given the properties of the $\{a_n\}$ sequence, we cannot say that $\{X_n\}$ is a supermartingale, because $(1)$ may not hold $\forall\, n$, or $(2)$ may not hold $\forall n\leq k$. But the following does hold :

$$ \forall n, \forall s \geq s(n), X_n \geq E[X_{n+s} \mid \mathcal F_n] \tag{7}$$

Verbally, standing at any $n$, if we look far enough into the future, we eventually expect to see consistently lower values of the $\{X_n\}$ sequence than the current one. But, standing at any $n$, there is an initial finite future period (for the index running from $n+1$ to $n + s(n) -1$), for which the supermartingale property may not hold.

From my original three questions, this one was the essential one:

**Does some kind of convergence obtains for $\{X_n\}$ when $(4)$ and $(5)$ hold?**

The process is not a supermartingale, but when a core property is violated only for a finite number of periods, and holds there after, the asymptotic results sometimes still hold. Although in our case, the core property is violated for a finite number of periods *always*, i.e. $\forall n$.

**Note:** A simple example of a process like $X_n$, is an $AR(1)$ with non-stochastic, time-varying autocorrelation coefficient whose sequence exhibits property $(4)$.

Comment: Imo the standard definition of a supermartingale is $$X_k \geq \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_k) \quad \text{for all $k \leq n$}.$$ This definition is equivalent to $(1)$ and has an obvious counterpart for continuous time processes.

Comment: "The representation of a supermartingale in continuous time looks more like relation (3) rather than relation (1)" Which representation? "I have seen characterizations of supermartingales in discrete time using relation (3) rather than (1)" This is odd. Any example of such a characterization you saw?

Comment: @saz Thank you, seeing it written by somebody else, helped me understand what I was mixing in my mind. Two of the three questions solved by your comment.

Comment: @Did Deleted all these, I just had things confused.